# how can I show user's location on embed google map?

Tags: google-maps

I'm following the tutorial from here https://developers.google.com/maps/tutorials/fundamentals/adding-a-google-map

and this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      #map {
        width: 500px;
        height: 400px;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
    <script>
      function initialize() {
        var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map');
        var mapOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(44.5403, -78.5463),
          zoom: 8,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }
        var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions)
      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

works like a charm. But it always shows the coordinates: `44.5403, -78.5463`. Is there any way to change it so that when user enters my page from new york, he will see the map of new york, and the guy from sydney will see sydney, etc?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do that, you have to use geolocation.

[Here is an example:](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-geolocation)

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var pos = {
        lat: position.coords.latitude,
        lng: position.coords.longitude
      };
```

Comment: Thank you. One question - I see in the example that I need to provide my api key there. I thought it's not necessary in maps v.3, but they require it in this example. Can you explain if I need to generate the key or not?

Comment: As far as I know you should do that. It wasn't required on the beginning of Google Map, but now it is. It's very easy to get it.